# How to fix a circular import with keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am getting an error when I run this code. I have already imported tensorflow but still i get an error due to a circular import. I'd be grateful if someone could help me out with this!

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)


model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)])


model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)
```

Comment: Please add the error you get when running the code

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\mohad\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py)

Comment: Plz add the error to your question not as a comment thy

Comment: @Mahi try not to mix up `from tensorflow import keras` with `tf.keras`. Just do `import tensorflow as tf` and use `tf.keras` everywhere.

Comment: @AloneTogether I did that in the first line, i just didnt copied that by mistake...

Comment: Remove `from tensorflow import keras` and use `tf.keras` everywhere.

Comment: @AloneTogether i still get the same error

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to demonstrate what I meant.

Comment: @AloneTogether thanks, but it still does not work

Comment: @Mahi Try to do  `tensorflow.keras.*`
You cоuld also trу tо сrеаtе аll thе rоutе fіlеѕ аnd іmроrt thеm іn main fіlе. If уоu іmроrt everything аt thе tор іt wоuld rеѕult іn a сіrсulаr іmроrt еrrоr.

Comment: You mean id need two files, one main file and another one where I write the code?

Comment: Given code just works fine with Tensorflow 2.7.0 on Colab. Try to uninstall existing Tensorflow and install latest Tensorflow version and Try your code. Thanks!